# How to temporary Replace SoftKeyboard View

Tags: android

i have seen the its possible to change View of the SoftKeyboard with another View, Like Stickers Page in the Viber, but i was not able to find out how is it possile to switch the screen and set it back whenever you want, Can any one Help here please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To avoid soft keyboard opening on activity start up You can use the following code in your manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.activity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" // Add this to your manifest
    android:label="@string/something">
</activity>
```

And to hide soft keyboard Onclick of a button, Use

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Then you can open the view you want

Comment: yes but my main point is where should i set my custom keyboard view?